# Snapshot not deleting

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a snapshot of a vm and when I tried to delete the snapshot it laughs in my face. I have been attempting to remove it for over a day now. It is acting like the initial snapshot was never completed before I tried to delete it so it is just hung.

The command I ran is this and selected yes to confirm the deletion:

***gcloud compute snapshots delete cp-disk-1-150921***

The error I get when I try to remove the vm:

***The resource 'projects/projectname/global/snapshots/cp-disk-1-150921' is not ready***

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can remove it?

Comment: If you list the snapshots, are you able to see the snapshot you are trying to delete? (gcloud compute snapshots list)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the reply. If I run that command it does show the snapshot with a status of DELETING. That status has not changed since I initially tried to delete it yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue that only Google could fix on their end.